# Syntax error caused near keyword "INNER JOIN" Caused by: SAP DBTech JDBC

Tags: sql, sql-server

I experiencing an issue with my SQL script. I read the SQL many times but can't see where the mistake is.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
        BKPF.BKTXT, BKPF.MONAT, BSEG.BELNR, BSEG.BUKRS, BSEG.DMBTR, BSEG.GJAHR, BSEG.MANDT, BSEG.PRCTR, BSEG.SAKNR, CEPCT.KTEXT, CEPCT.LTEXT, SKAT.MCOD1, SKAT.TXT20, SKAT.TXT50 
FROM 
        (((SAPPR1.BSEG
　　INNER JOIN SAPPR1.BKPF ON BSEG.GJAHR = BKPF.GJAHR)
　    INNER JOIN (
　　　　SELECT
　　　　　　SAKNR, TXT20, TXT50, MCOD1
　　　　FROM
　　　　　　SAPPR1.SKAT
　　　　WHERE
　　　　　　SPRAS not LIKE  '%[a-z0-9 .]%'
        ))) AS SKAT_SUB ON BSEG.SAKNR = SKAT_SUB.SAKNR
　　INNER JOIN SAPPR1.CEPCT ON BSEG.PRCTR = CEPCT.PRCTR)
WHERE
        BSEG.GJAHR = (SELECT Year('?')-1 HAVING Month('?')-1 < 4)  
        OR BSEG.GJAHR = (SELECT Year('?') HAVING Month('?')-1 > 3)
        AND BKPF.MONAT =  (SELECT Month('?')-1)  
        AND BSEG.MANDT=?
;
```

This is the error message I am receiving:

> Caused by: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "　　INNER": line 5 col 1 (at pos 216)

So we know that the syntax error is around the INNER JOIN Keywords. There must be extra ')' elements, but which ones.

Please enlighten. I would be grateful to you.

Comment: You missed the clause `SELECT` in `(SAPPR1.BSEG INNER JOIN SAPPR1.BKPF ON BSEG.GJAHR = BKPF.GJAHR)`.

Comment: "Too many parentheses error"